# Excel Pivot Table: Multiply a Subtotal by a Scalar

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I've tried quite a bit of things and looked all over the net but can't seem to find a solution.

**Goal:** Summarize number of sales per salesperson per quarter and per year.

**My data:**

[image: Data Table]

**My initial pivot table:**

[image: Pivot Table]

Note that the values shown on the pivot table are a calculated field set up as follows.

[image]

**What's working:**  The pivot table is calculating the number of sales per salesperson per quarter correctly.

**What's not working (the way I want it to):** I would like to multiple the 2013 Total by a scalar.  For example, with respect to USA, I would like 2013 Total to equal 9.32 (2.33 * 4)

**What I've tried:**  As a cheat, I could see that showing the value of the quarter as a "Running Total in" may work, yielding 9.5 (2.00 + 3.00 + 2.00 + 2.50); but I can't seem to have that apply only on the column subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the nearest possible to what you require may look something like this:

[image: SO21167717 example]

assuming non-OLAP source data and a Calculated Field of `='Sales per Person'*4` in Σ Values, because of two restraints mentioned [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/calculate-values-in-a-pivottable-report-HP010096323.aspx):

- Formulas cannot refer to totals
- Formulas for calculated items operate on the individual records